# Windows 10 Custom Scaling - Why is DPI value rounded?

Tags: windows-10, high-dpi

I've a PC with a 4k 27" screen. The screen has a physical DPI value of 163.2 = sqrt(3840^2 + 2160^2)/27. But that's not the DPI value my question is about.

I was wondering why my full screen windows size is 2394 x 1346 and not 2400 x 1350 when I set the custom scaling to 160%

I saw that Windows 10 rounds the [DPI value](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.graphics.dpix) from 96 * 1.6 = 153.6 up to 154. But why?

When I set the scaling to 150% the maximum size is 2560 x 1440 and the DPI value is 144. With 100% scaling the maximum size is 3840 x 2160 and the DPI value is 96.

Comment: Where 96 comes from?

Comment: @MátéJuhász 96 DPI is the 100% value. It is not related to physical pixel density.

Comment: 144 DPI is 150% value and 153.6 DPI would be the 160% value

Comment: The custom DPI value is stored under `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop\LogPixels` as an integer. But why do they store the custom DPI value and not the scaling factor in percent?

Answer (score 2):

Screen resolution is measured in Pixels (lots of references) and that is the lowest unit of measurement. There is not a fraction of a pixel, so the calculation must be expressed in Pixels.

Example site:

https://www.techwalla.com/articles/how-is-resolution-measured

Comment: `3840/1.6 = 2400` and not `2394 = round(3840/154*96)`

Comment: DPI or PPI isn’t pixels. It’s pixel density. I very much doubt most screens have pixels that align cleanly to inches. And then, this is about relative pixel density with a non-integer scaling factor, so the calculation results will almost never align to physical pixels anyway.

Comment: That may be the list of resolutions for a full screen measurement and these are often a specific value. That is a full physical screen will have a specific value in a list. My virtual screens are unrounded, but whole, pixel values.